# Add Days to Dates Unless Friday vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel spreadsheet to populate a 6-day rotation calendar(Days 1-6).  In the event of a snow day, we resume the next school day on the snow day's schedule.  I am trying to write vba to add 1 day to all highlighted (I manually highlight) dates unless it's a Friday, then add 3.

Here is the code I have so far (I have also tried many other variations).  It seems to skip over my If statement to the Else statement.  (meaning it will add 1 day as intended, but not add 3 days to Friday).  Your help would be appreciated.  Thanks,Kim

```
Sub Add_Day_To_Range()

Dim c As Range
Dim Wkday As Integer
Wkday = Weekday(#1/6/2020#, vbMonday)

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
      If Wkday = 5 Then
      c.Value = c.Value + 3
      Else: c.Value = c.Value + 1
      End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: `Weekday(#1/6/2020#, vbMonday)` equals `1`, so `If Wkday = 5` will always be `False`. You need to test the weekday of `c`.

Comment: Just a note, you can use the built-in Excel `Workday` function to do this. You can just do it on the spreadsheet, but if you want to do it in VBA, it would look like `c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(c.Value, 1)`

Comment: @JoshEller - add as an answer and I'll upvote, that is a good point, no need to re-invent functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the weekday into the loop should solve it. May not quite work depending on the date format in your cells but should be close

```
Sub Add_Day_To_Range()

Dim c As Range
Dim Wkday As Integer

For Each c In Selection.Cells
  Wkday = Weekday(c.Value, vbMonday)
  If Wkday = 5 Then
  c.Value = c.Value + 3
  Else: c.Value = c.Value + 1
  End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a little trouble understanding what was in the  c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Workday(c.Value, 1) statement.  When I ran it, 2-4 days was added to my dates.  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Since workday(c.value, 1) means count the weekdays starting from Sunday, it was adding an extra 1 day by counting from Sunday not Monday. If you're happy with my answer could you accept it please?